# What is Lightning Web Runtime (LWR) - outside of the context of Experience Cloud?

Tags: lightning-web-components, winter22, lightning-web-runtime

Lightning Web Runtime, outside of the context of Experience Cloud, has been featured on the [Create User Experiences with Lightning Web Components](https://www.salesforce.com/plus/experience/Dreamforce_2021/series/Developer/episode/episode-1) episode at Dreamforce. What is this pilot about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LWR](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/overview) is a way to configure and load the modules, services, and dependency providers you need to build a JavaScript app. You can deploy on a variety of runtime environments, depending on your use case. For example, LWR works in a local Node.js runtime, or as a standalone instance in Heroku.

[image: LWR staticsite]

You can start by building a simple static website in your local environment. Simply run `npm init lwr` and follow the wizard steps to scaffold a LWC static site or a single page application.

[image: SPA project files]